# C3P0 exhausted after call some @Transactional methods

Tags: multi-tenant, c3p0, hibernate-5.x

I've implemented a multi tenant architecture and I've introduced a `C3P0` connection pool.

By GUI I try to query my application with a simple search form. THis form has a button to call a back end method to extract my result.

If I click several times my search I've my application freeze because C3P0 connection pool is exhausted.

Because `C3P0` increment connections managed with `acquireIncrement` parameter but when it arrived `MAX_SIZE` crashes

**So my scenario is the follow:**

I've a class annoted as `@Service` and a method annoted as `@Transactional` where I'm executing my query, as follow:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public String findPatientCountDao(Paziente paziente, 
    boolean searchForAllPatients, boolean enabledDemetra) {
    String querySqlOrHql = this.createQuery(paziente, searchForAllPatients, true, 0, 0);

    Query q = getSession().createQuery(querySqlOrHql);
    List<Object[]> obj = q.list();
    return "" + obj.get(0);
}
```

**My Hibernate configuration has managed by HibernateConf class, as follow:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConf {

@Autowired
DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl dataSources;
@Autowired
TenantSchemaResolver tenantSchemaResolver;


@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    if (TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()==null)
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("tenant_1");
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSources.selectDataSource(TenantContext.getCurrentTenant()));
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("it.spi");
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
    configuration.setProperties(hibernateProperties());

    //sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate_ehr/hibernate.cfg.xml"));

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
        sessionFactory = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager =
            new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}


private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, dataSources);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantSchemaResolver);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.USE_STREAMS_FOR_BINARY, true);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.DRIVER, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, false);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, false);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.USE_SQL_COMMENTS, false);
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.C3P0_MIN_SIZE, 50);         //Minimum size of pool
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.C3P0_MAX_SIZE, 100);        //Maximum size of pool
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, 10);//Number of connections acquired at a time when pool is exhausted 
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.C3P0_TIMEOUT, 1800);       //Connection idle time
    hibernateProperties.put(Environment.C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, 600); //PreparedStatement cache size
    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

**My Datasource configuration:**

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = { "dataSource", "dataSource1" })
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource1")
public DataSource dataSource1() {
    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder
            .create(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getClassLoader())
            .driverClassName(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getDriverClassName())
            .username(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUsername())
            .password(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getPassword())
            .url(this.multitenancyProperties.getDatasource1().getUrl()).type(ComboPooledDataSource.class);
    return factory.build();
}
```

**My database.properties file**

```
spring.multitenancy.datasource.type = com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource
spring.multitenancy.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xx.xx:1521/xxx
spring.multitenancy.datasource.username=xxx
spring.multitenancy.datasource.password=yyy
spring.multitenancy.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.multitenancy.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.multitenancy.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.multitenancy.datasource.hibernate.c3p0.max_size=100
spring.multitenancy.datasource.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```